# MYSQL .CSV File prevent excel from convert value to date

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, multiplication

I want to make an .csv file out of an mysql table and I need to multiply two columns. It works,  but after I open this file in excel the solution sometimnes becomes a date (2.04 becomes 2.april) ...

Another way would be to put an '=' or ' ' in front of the number, but I don't know how to do this in an sql-query

Comment: What did you try so far? Olgidos.doRead([ask])

Comment: i tried something like this  " '=' (menge * netto_wert) as wert" in my sql query

Comment: i tried to set off the auto convertation from excel .. but it seems, that this isnt possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reliable way to open a delimited text file (.csv, .txt, etc) in Excel is, IMHO, this:

Save the file as .txt (or simply rename if it's a .csv).
Excel > File > Open > point to the .txt file.

You will now see a dialog that you wouldn't see if the file was a .csv. You can now select the formatting for each column (be it General, Text, Date, etc.).

Select text for all of the problematic ones and you're good to go!

EDIT:

To simply concatenate '=' to the product of the two columns, use:

```
SELECT datum, produkt_id, name, menge, von, nach, concat('=',menge * netto_wert) as wert FROM
```

Comment: Alternatively you can open the same dialog in Excel without renaming the file by selecting "From text" in the group "Get External Data" of the menu Data.

Comment: thx, but i know this already ... but this is not a good solution, becouse its to complicated for bureau-womenens and i need a way to do this automatic

Comment: sry but this isnt an option =/

Comment: isnt there any way to format the output of a multiplication in sql?

Comment: Post your select statement, from "select" up to "from". We'll help you modify that.

Comment: SELECT datum, produkt_id, name, menge, von, nach, (menge * netto_wert) as wert FROM

Comment: Try SELECT datum, produkt_id, name, menge, von, nach, concat('=',menge * netto_wert) as wert FROM

Comment: ok nice works a bit better, but excel gives now =2,05, propably the correct way is ='2,05'

Comment: is this possible? ... i found an other way with concat(' ',menge * netto_wert), this is an option aswell.

Comment: Can you guys please update both the question and answer with the useful information from the comments. Further readers will think, that there is no way to do this, because the root cause of the problem and the answer is hidden in the comments.

Comment: @Pred - as soon as we reach a satisfactory answer, we will.

Comment: @Olgidos - If you ask me, it's not fine - if you select the excel sheet, copy the value and paste to text editor you still have that empty space before the value, right?

Comment: There is a big checkmark next to this answer. This means on this site, that the answer is satisfactory.